# How to access model attribute in dust.js section

Tags: backbone.js, dust.js

I want to know how to access model attribute which is array, inside dust section {#} {/}.

```
MODEL:

"a":new array();

"b":{
 "c":new array();
}

DUST TEMPLATE:

{#a}
 want to access {c} here...
{/a}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access `{#c}` when you are inside the `{#a}`. First you need to go up with `{#b}` then inside there you need to go down to `c` with {#a}.

So you will need something like this:

```
{#a}
    {name}
    {#b}        
      {#c}
         {name}
      {/c}
    {/b}        
{/a}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WUwLx/).